# Oracle search in all tables for a value results in ORA-31011

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I found this query on Stack Overflow to search for a particular string in all tables.

```
set SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 100000

DECLARE
  match_count INTEGER;
BEGIN
  FOR t IN (SELECT owner, table_name, column_name
            FROM all_tab_columns
        WHERE owner <> 'SYS' and data_type IN ('CHAR', 'VARCHAR2', 'NCHAR', 'NVARCHAR')) LOOP
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || t.owner || '.' || t.table_name ||
    ' WHERE ' || t.column_name || ' = :1'
    INTO match_count
    USING 'my own string';

IF match_count > 0 THEN
  dbms_output.put_line(t.table_name || ' ' || t.column_name || ' ' || match_count);
END IF;
END LOOP;
END;
```

I get the following errors when running this

> ORA-31011: XML Interpretation was not performed ORA-19202: An error occurred while processing XML
>   LPX-00200: Could not convert from encoding UTF-8 to WINDOWS-1252 Error at line 1
>   ORA-06512: vid rad 7 31011. 00000 - "XML parsing failed"
>
> *Cause: XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
>
> *Action: Check if the document to be parsed is valid. I am very new in oracle and learning as I go

Why is it giving an XML parsing error even though I don't use XML? How do I resolve this error?

When I had only CHAR as data_type, it worked but didn't show any output. Is is because there is no output or it went somewhere else? In that case, how to check the output?

Comment: Could you please provide the full error stack for this? Also wrap the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE in a `begin ... end;` and add an exception handler to output the owner, table name and column name of the erroring record then post the output from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS for that record.

Comment: @Ben, thank you for your reply. This is the error record I got.

Error report -
ORA-31011: XML Interpretation was not performed
ORA-19202: An error occurred while processing XML 
LPX-00200: Could not convert from encoding UTF-8 to WINDOWS-1252
Error at line 1
ORA-06512: vid rad 7
31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
*Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
*Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.

I am very new in oracle and learning as I go. Thanks again.

Comment: What was the actual dynamic query that failed, and how is that column defined?